# CefSharp Running JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am having difficulty running JS in CefSharp due to the command running straight after each other. Basically, I need a wait command to await the page to load after executing the last script.

Hence it would be:

```html
await Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script1);
Browser.WaitForLoad();
Task<JavascriptResponse> test = await Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script2);
```

I have found a few resources but I'm only new to programming so I'm finding it a bit difficult to work out how I can do what I want.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.Wpf;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string MessagesInbox;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Browser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Browser.LoadingStateChanged += async (Sender, args) => {if (args.IsLoading == false)
                {
                    await Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"document.getElementById('User').value = 'test'; document.getElementById('Password').value = 'password'; document.getElementById('LoginButton').click();");
                }};
            Task<JavascriptResponse> test = Browser.EvaluateScriptAsPromiseAsync(@"return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, { var test = ''; document.querySelectorAll('.MasterAction').forEach(el => test += el.children[3].children[0].href + ', ')}), 2000);");
            MessagesInbox = test.Result.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(MessagesInbox);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with your current code?

Comment: Currently, I get a "System.Exception: 'Unable to execute javascript at this time, scripts can only be executed within a V8Context" error. But I need the page to wait for load before sending the second command that returns a Task<JavascriptResponse>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also check the `IsLoading` for your second method, you can use a bool to track if you are already logged in, and use the second method inside that function aswell like this:

```
public bool loggedIn = false;
private void Browser_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Browser.LoadingStateChanged += async (Sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.IsLoading == false)
            {
                if (!loggedIn)
                {
                    await Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"document.getElementById('User').value = 'test'; document.getElementById('Password').value = 'password'; document.getElementById('LoginButton').click();")
                        .ContinueWith(x =>
                        {
                            var response = x.Result;
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.Result);
                            if (response.Result == null)
                            {
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("should be changed to true");
                                loggedIn = true;
                            }
                        });
                }
                else
                {
                    JavascriptResponse test = await Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"var test = ''; document.querySelectorAll('.MasterAction').forEach(el => test += el.children[3].children[0].href + ', ');test.substr(0,test.length-2)");
                    MessagesInbox = test.Result.ToString();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(MessagesInbox);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you call Reload? The EvaluateScriptAsPromiseAsync call can be awaited

Comment: @amaitland You are right actually no need for it, I updated my answer

Comment: @AbdullahAkçam, Thank you heaps for your help. I didn't need to use the promise so I ended up with the code I submitted as an edit.

I have a [reddit post]{https://www.reddit.com/r/CefSharp/comments/q0fcgv/cefsharp_wait_for_load/} that was also discussing this too and have posted the answer there.

You can use this method and use an int instead of a bool and use if(x==1){}else if (x==2){} and so forth to step down the commands.

Newbies, keep in mind that the System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() is just to write a line to the output shell in VS studio.